# Removing curly braces outside texs math-mode

Tags: php, regex, curly-braces, math-mode

I want to have curly braces removed outside texs math-mode. For example:

```
Lorem Ipsum $\mathbb{R}$ dolore. {Author} $\{1,\dotsc,n}$
```

should become:

```
Lorem Ipsum $\mathbb{R}$ dolore. Author $\{1,\dotsc,n}$
```

As you can't really negate regular expressions I was looking into look-aheads and -behinds. That wasn't working for me as technically speaking, {Author} also is between two dollar signs. Some regex professional having some advice for me?

I'd love to only use preg_replace when the problem isn't too complex for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
$re = '/\$\\\w*{[^}]+}(*SKIP)(*F)|{[^}]*}/'; 
$str = "Lorem Ipsum \$\mathbb{R}\$ dolore. {Author} \${1,\dotsc,n}\$"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, '', $str);

//=> Lorem Ipsum $\mathbb{R}$ dolore.  Author $\{1,\dotsc,n}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tV1kN8/9)

Here we are using PCRE verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)` to skip the math-mode blocks and replace `{` and `}` in rest of the text:

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, I've added that option as well in answer

Comment: Thank you very much, I checked the execution time for both on my 2.1GHz Dual-Core laptop with PHP 5.5.9. The difference is noticeable but small. 100k preg_replace calls and then averaged gives roughly: negative-lookahead: 4.5*10^-6 sec/preg_replace and PCRE: 4.0*10^-6 sec/preg_replace

Comment: I noticed that the regex would remove all curly braces for such cases: "$\mathbb{R} $ dolore. {Author}" Do you have some advice what needs to be changed to also work when there are white-spaces before the dollar?

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much.